# WordPress - update language files

Tags: wordpress, translation, upgrade

I installed WordPress 3.8 in english language. I'm thinking about change default language (manual upload translation files).

But there's something I don't know: does WordPress itself will be able to upgrade this files in the future?

Answer (score 3):

Yes .. It will.

You also need to change the language code in the `wp-config.php`

the default is :

```
define ('WPLANG', '');
```

Change it to the language code you need :

Example ( German )

```
define ('WPLANG', 'de_DE');
```

or Italian

```
define ('WPLANG', 'it_IT');
```

Since, however, from your question I can safely assume that you are not a high-level developer , it would be better if you will just download the whole WP package in your language , ( you can find the list [HERE](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language) ) and upload it to your server . ( meaning - re-install / upgrade ).

The reason I am saying that is that since wp 3.8 there is somewhat of a new system to handle language upgrades separately , and thus also new folders ( Languages ).

Just be careful not to overwrite the old wp-content folder , and also not the old `wp-config.php` providing that you made the changes described above . ( But remember , if wp3.8 you need the new language folder in `wp-content` )

If you have not made those changes , just overwrite also the , but remember to update all the other info ( like `DB name` , `DB address` , `DB User` and `DB password` , and also the `Unique Keys and Salts`.